# using AJAX query to pass javascript array to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

After reading through quite a few posts here, (and even just straight copying code,) I still cannot figure out why this is not working.

On my main page, I have a textbox that a user pastes data into.  Upon paste, this script runs (this **and** the ajax query below are in the same script function):

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');  //create array from pasted data
```

I now have a JavaScript array with the pasted data.  I'm trying to send this over to a separate PHP file that I will load into a div on this main page by doing the following:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'return.php',
      data: {lines:lines},        
        success:function(data){
          $("#info").load("return.php");
        }
  });

  for (i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {            // log the output
    if (lines[i]){
    console.log("line ",  i , lines[i]);
    }  
  }
```

In my `return.php` file, I have this:

```
$lines = $_REQUEST['lines'];

echo '<pre>';
echo($lines);
echo '</pre>';
```

My console.log is outputting the array perfectly, but for some reason it is not making its way over to return.php, as my echo is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

The response I get from return.php is:

```
 <pre>testArrayArray
(
    [0] => DL4004-13-F
    [1] => S1G-13-F
    [2] => ZXMP3A13FTA
    [3] => B260A-13-F
    [4] => S1J-13-F
    [5] => S3B-13-F
    [6] => SSN1N45BTA
    [7] => GBJ1010-F
    [8] => BPW20RF
    [9] => T3035H-6I
    [10] => ZXMP7A17KTC
    [11] => 
)
</pre>
```

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger whether the data is being sent to the server?

Comment: Looking at the php_error_log file I don't see anything....

Comment: Check your browser's debugger (the networking tab in Chrome's dev tools, for example).

Comment: Oh ok, I see.  I haven't used this before, but I think I found the right object.  I do see a POST action to return.php with all of the variables that are part of this.  I've updated my original question with the response I get from the server...

Comment: What do you expect `data` to be in your ajax callback if you type `1\n2\n3`  and send the ajax request?

Comment: an array consisting of 3 values: 1, 2, and 3.  Is that not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success handler on your ajax request is calling return.php with nothing and loading it into #info.

Change success to instead do:

```
$("#info").html(data)
```

Comment: Hmmm - so the `succcess` portion of the AJAX code is not like an "on success, do this." That's what I thought I was saying: "on success of posting `lines` to return.php, load return.php"

Comment: The initial POST succeeds & you get back the data. Then the code immediately loads return.php again but this time without any parameters so you get back an empty set of pre tags that are loaded into the #info element

Comment: so the (data) in the line `success:function(data)`, is the actual information inside of my `lines` array?  I don't get how return.php actually gets loaded - where in the code am I telling it to load that page?   I'm confused.... :/

Comment: 'success' is the function handler when the call to $.ajax() completes successfully and contains the output of the POSTing to the url you specified. Checkout the documentation for all the details http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

The `$lines` variable in your PHP code is an array, not a string. If you have the errors turned on, PHP should warn you that you're doing an "Array to string conversion" (at least it does for me using your code).

You can't `echo` an array like that, you have to iterate through the results somehow.

Comment: The `echo` did a good enough job of showing what the array contains, didn't it?

Comment: He did say that his AJAX request returns "blank" though. I don't know enough to explain why he has the output from his $.load (that's what I understand) and not from the AJAX request. Can you really `echo` an array like that .. ? @JuanMendes

Comment: That's true, `echo($lines)` outputs `Array`, what the OP showed is the output of `print_r($lines)` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/817e1b35ae41b7ff1e94c6a66a1fa0c3acb97809

Comment: totally - thank you for that.  I used print_r instead, and I get the output.  Thank you so much!